# How to position an svg image X pixels in a div using css?

Tags: html, css

I have multiple div boxes, each of differing widths.

How do I position the svg image 10 pixels from the right of each div ?

I've tried using percentages but it didn't work.

Below is my code:

```
select {
    background-image: url(caret-down.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 92% 50%;
}
```

So this centers the svg vertically and 92% to the left of the div.

Answer (score 0):

ok I fixed it while searching...

```
select {
    background-image: url(caret-down.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right 10px center;
}
```

Comment: you could use a pseudo element to make it css2 compatible